# Click action only not working in mareshmallow

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the my full xml ....where inside linear layout action click is not working fully in marshmallow 6.0.But,in other android version up-to 5.1 its working perfectly.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@color/appnewcolor"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

                <com.unikkapps.android.contest.utils.Text
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="Flickty" />
             </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
         </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.unikkapps.android.contest.utils.TablayoutCustom
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/appnewcolor"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white_87" />

          </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bt_bar_home" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bt_bar_search" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_plus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bt_bar_camera" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/watchpost_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_cam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bt_bar_notification" />

                <com.unikkapps.android.contest.utils.Text
                    android:id="@+id/notificationcount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv_cam"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv_cam"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iv_cam"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/appnewcolor"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contest_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_context"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bt_bar_contest" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thank you for your help guys in advance.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question ? which action you are taking for getting click event ?

Comment: @TejasRana It's in his `LinearLayout` with id of `bottom`.

Comment: yes its Linearlayout with id bottom@TejasRana

Comment: i have added ans let me know is it working or not ? @SonuKunwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add property in your Linear layout as below,

**android:onClick="onClick"**

and add method in your Java class,

```
   public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.bottom:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"on click works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

It's Work, Tested in both 5.0 and 6.0

Comment: For home & search icon on click is not working.But,camera,notification & contest icon onclick is working @Tejas Rana

Comment: if in on click i try to perform any action that also not working.But,just now i got that what is the problem...problem on marshmallow 6.0 permissions,if i go from mobile sitting ,after the my application and grant all permissions ......then onclick perform very well.otherwise its won't...........now my problem how to i  do grant permission for marshmallow 6.0 programmatically ??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html refer this for your new question.

Comment: Thank u very much @tejas